# What is the working principle of electric arc lighters?

Tags: everyday-life, plasma-physics

How do electric arc lighters work? The wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighter#Electric_Arc_lighter) about this is very short. So I understand that there is a current at low voltage that leaps over air and turns it into plasma, but what then is the purpose of four points that create a cross of plasma like in this [company](https://www.plazmatic.com/)'s products? Is this a new invention or just perfected enough in recent years (batteries with enough capacity?) to be suitable for hand held battery driven lighters?

[image]

The image of the lighter is taken from [here](http://www.electricarclighter.com/product/double-electrical-arc-lighter-usb-rechargeable-windproof/).

Ps. Sorry for asking multiple questions at once but they all seem interrelated to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the crossed-arc trick is a way of stabilizing the formation of the arc. this was learned over 100 years ago when arcs were used in a primitive radio transmitter called a spark gap transmitter. these fell out of use after vacuum tubes were invented but in the years before that, lots of clever experimental work went into making arcs stable and repeatable, and the multi-electrode arc was one of them.